# MVC Model is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Using the MVC Framework i get an simple problem.

```
@model mvc_test.Models.HomeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<li>@Model.OutputEmail</li>//Error NullReferenceException

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.OutputEmail, new { @class = "Label"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OutputEmail)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.OutputEmail)
```

So my thought is the Linq Expression (x=>...) always creates a new instance of the class. So i need to pass the model trough my view or is there a better solution. Since i can access the model through the linq expresions.

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Comment: According to the comment in your code, the error is happening *before* the "Linq expressions", so why would you think they're related at all?  *Are you* supplying an instance of the model to the view?

Comment: are you returning your model in your View?  I bet that's the issue.  Also I think you have a gross misunderstanding of what LINQ is

Comment: You have to return the model with the view, in your controller action. Most commonly... return View(model); // Where model has been instantiated

(Your "Linq Expressions" are Lambda Expressions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
@Model.OutputEmail
```

references the instance of the model passed to the view.  However, *this* code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.OutputEmail)
```

does *not* reference an actual instance of the model.  It reflects into the *type* of the model and produces the markup intended for that type.

So if you're not passing a model to the view then the first line will fail because the *instance* of the model is `null`, but the second will succeed because the *type* of the model is still known.

Comment: So the LabelFor method creates an instance. Somebody need to do it or not? I can not gain data from nothing.

Comment: @MR.ABC: No, `LabelFor` doesn't create an instance of the model.  It creates HTML markup.  The point is that you don't need to supply an instance of a model in order to use `LabelFor`.  But you *do* need to supply an instance of a model in order to reference the value of an instance property on that model.  Which has nothing to do with `LabelFor` or similar HTML helper methods.

Comment: I know that LabelFor creates the HTML markup. Somewhere in the MVC a instance of the model needs to be created to get the data.

Comment: @MR.ABC: Yes, you supply an instance of the model when you pass control to the view from the controller.  Something like:  `return View(someModelInstance);`  The framework doesn't create an instance for you.

Comment: Yep... I know. The callstack of LabelFor will create somewhere a instance of the model. Thats what i like to say.

Comment: @MR.ABC: No, it doesn't.  Why do you think it does?  What would it even do with such an instance?  All `LabelFor` needs is the meta-data from the *type* of the model.  It doesn't need an instance.  *If* an instance is passed to the view then that can be used to populate *values* in the rendered markup.  But the instance isn't required to create the markup itself.  The actual error you're getting is from an entirely different line of code, one which *does* need an instance because it tries to de-reference a value from that instance.

Comment: I'm sure it does. What it will do with the metadata? The metadata can not give any values. Just information about the class. Somewhere an object needs to be created. But i don't like to start a discussion.

Comment: @MR.ABC: You can believe whatever you like, but the very code you posted in the question and the error you found demonstrates otherwise.  The line of code giving the error needs a model instance, the line of code not giving the error doesn't.  Some HTML helpers (the ones which display values) *can use* an instance of a model if one is supplied.  But they don't *need* one.  (Without one they simply don't display a value.)  And they most certainly don't *create* one for you.  (The framework has no way of knowing what values you would want on your business object.)

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OutputEmail) gives me a value without creating a instance by my own.

Comment: @MR.ABC: If the view has a model with a value on it, yes.  If it *doesn't* have a model then it might display a default from the type's meta-data.  Otherwise, assuming that's a string, the default is null or empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is null. You can either use `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.OutputEmail)` or you can check for null and then not try to output the value if it is null. Or you could create an object for the model in the controller.